# How to make "Copy to clipboard" button/link in django admin for selected field?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I use classic Django Admin panel. I want to add button/link for on of the fields in model.

What is the simplest way to do that?

Comment: As far as I know you can't. The simplest way I know of doing copy to clipboard button on website is using Adobe Flash

Comment: check if this might be of any help https://github.com/mdornseif/django-clippy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me show you how you can display a button next to a field in Django admin using Javascript.

First of all, you'll need to know the HTML element `id` of that field. To know the `id` of an 
element in Chrom/Firefox: *Right click on the input field > Inspect Element*.

Let's say I have a field called `name` in my models, 
its HTML element `id`, as assigned by Django admin interface would be `id_name`

So if I want to display a a button next to it I'd write this JS script:

```
var $ = django.jQuery;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var myButton = '<button>Copy</button>';
    $(myButton).insertAfter($('#id_name'));
});
```

Save this file in your project's `/static/` folder. I named it `show-copy-btn.js`.

Then supply this file to your model admin's add/change page using [`class Media`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/media/), like this:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    class Media:
        js = ('show-copy-btn.js',) 
        # above path is equivalent to /static/show-copy-btn.js
        # if your file in /static/js/ folder, the path above should 
        # be 'js/show-copy-btn.js'
```

If you open the add/change admin page of your model, you will see a button next 
to the desired field. Although, the button may look a little ugly, I'm sure you can make it pretty via some CSS magic.

Hope this answer gets you started. After this, you can write the JS code for the actual "Copy to clipboard" feature and pass that code to Django admin just like I showed you above.

**NOTE:** This answer doesn't show you how to copy text to clipboard. It only shows you how you can display a button next to a field in Django admin using JS.

Answer (score 4):

Today I stumbled upon this problem and [xyres answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32025573/5494684) above. But instead of including a static file (which might lead to other trouble e.g. having two different targets) I though about a method field style and came up with this:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


class AttachmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    .
    .

    readonly_fields = (
        'options',
    )

    def options(self, obj):
        btn_id = 'copy-helper'
        return mark_safe(f"""
            <input text="text" id="{btn_id}" value="{obj.media_url}" style="position: absolute; top: -10000px">
            <a href="#" onclick="document.querySelector(\'#{btn_id}\').select(); document.execCommand(\'copy\');" class="addlink">Copy media url to clipboard</a>
            """
        )
    options.short_description = _('Options')
```

Which leads to:
[image: Django Admin Preview]

This way the appeareance can easily be customized and if needed one can extend the javascript to fetch the input(type="text") field value from other html tags via queryselector first.

Hope this might be useful for others.

Comment: For anyone wondering why on mobile the keyboard opens and the screen moves to the top right corner, just add `readonly` property to the input field to prevent this behaviour.